# Fetch the value from the key PHP

Tags: php

I have a wordy value array without explisit keys for speed reason. And the keys are populated as numeric keys 0-N automatically:

```
$array = array('Good old days', 'Bad old days', ....);
```

The form is filled up with expected key|value pairs:

```
key=0, value=Good old days
```

or

```
<option value="0">Good old days</option>
```

which is good as I don't want to have long wordy keys.

Now the issue part is, I know how to fetch the key, but I can not find a way how to display the value out of the given key. Maybe because I have to loop for a condition and than the key is grabbed if the condition met.

How do you grab the value from the given key?

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

```
  //If keys are wordy: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento|Droid+Sans|Yanone+Kaffeesatz

  $gwf_settings = array(
    'base_font',
    'article_title',
    'site_name',
    'site_slogan',   
  );


  $gwfs = array();
  foreach($gwf_settings as $key => $gwf_font) { 
    //dsm('KEYS: '. $key); 
    // parent form to check condition if we are using gwf
        if (theme_get_setting($gwf_font) == 'gwf') {
          $values = $gwfs[theme_get_setting($gwf_font .'_gwf')];
            dsm('KEY2: '. theme_get_setting($gwf_font .'_gwf')); //ok, we have the gwf key
            dsm('VALUES: '. $values); // BLANK        
$gwfs[] = str_replace(' ', '+',  $values);
        }       
  }    

  $google_web_fonts = implode('|', $gwfs);
```

I seem to get stucked with "values".

**UPDATE 2**, in case useful to anyone, or any betterment:

```
          $gwf_settings = array(
            'base_font',
            'article_title',
            'site_name',
            'site_slogan',   
          );

          $gwf_gwf = array(
            'base_font_gwf',
            'article_title_gwf',
            'site_name_gwf',
            'site_slogan_gwf',   
          );  

          foreach($gwf_settings as $key => $gwf_font) {     
            if ( theme_get_setting($gwf_font) == 'gwf' ) {       
              $gwfs = array();
              foreach ($gwf_gwf as $k => $gwf_setting) {   
                $s = theme_get_setting($gwf_setting);         
                $fonts = get_gwf();     
                if ( $s ) { 
                  foreach ($fonts as $f => $val) {
                    if ( $f == $s ) {                 
                      $gwfs[] = str_replace(' ', '+',  $val);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }   

          $google_web_fonts = implode('|', $gwfs); 

        // The final output will be just like with wordy key version: 
//http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Droid+Sans
```

Comment: You mean something else than $array[ key ] ?

Comment: I think I need to do another 2 loops for "something else"

Comment: I have to do another loop for the setting and finally another loop for the fonts, willy nilly :). Thanks for the hint all along

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $array[0]` will print 'Good old days'.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the key, you can use it [the same as always](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
$array[$key]
```